How to remove the grey background of my letters/characters?
When I am typing, there is annoying grey background behind what I typed.
Look at this grey background behind my charaters: (This is a markdown cell in VS Code + Jupyter)

Can I remove the grey background?
Thanks!
What I did ?
did nothing
...
sorry. I don't know what to do.
I searched web. cannont find a solution
